# How to delete options in a dropdown list with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic dropdown list made of a parent-dropdown and a child-dropdown. I have a script that disables options in a child-dropdown when an option in the parent-dropdown is selected.

Instead of disabling it, I would like to completely remove the options in the child-dropdown so they won't be available.

```js
"use strict";

window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('category_select').addEventListener("change", function() {

    function parent_() {
      let i = document.getElementById('category_select');
      let j = i.options[i.selectedIndex].value;
      return j;
    }

    function child_() {
      let k = document.getElementById('type_select');
      for (let i = 0; i < k.options.length; ++i) {
        if (k.options[i].value === parent_()) {
          k.options[i].disabled = false;
        } else if (k.options[i].value !== parent_()) {
          k.options[i].disabled = true; //options get disabled and I would like to delete them ...
        }
      }
    }
    child_()
  });
};
```

```html
<select id="category_select">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Electronics</option>
  <option value="2">Appliances</option>
</select>

<select id="type_select">
  <option value="" disabled="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Phones</option>
  <option value="1">Tablets</option>
  <option value="2" disabled="">Couch</option>
  <option value="2" disabled="">Refrigerator</option>
  <option value="2" disabled="">Vacuum</option>
</select>
```

Basically, when the option with the value of 1 is selected in `category_select`, all options in `type_select` with a value of 2 are disabled. I would like to delete them.

What is a simple and elegant way of doing this?

***EDIT***

Looks like the best solution for doing this can be found there `http://jsfiddle.net/Lcjp2xav/1/` and has been provided by @Jagjeet Singh

Comment: you can set `<optgroup>` and then it would be easy. note: 2 `<option>` can not have the same value. that is semantically wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `k.options[i].style.display`, if you want to completely remove then option then use `k.options[i].remove()`

```js
function parent_() {
 let i = document.getElementById('category_select');
 let j = i.options[i.selectedIndex].value;
 return j;
}

function child_() {
 let k = document.getElementById('type_select');
 for (let i = 0; i < k.options.length; ++i) {
  if (k.options[i].value === parent_()) {
   k.options[i].style.display = 'block';
   k.options[i].disabled = false;
  } else if (k.options[i].value !== parent_()) {
   k.options[i].style.display = 'none';
   k.options[i].disabled = true;
  }
 }
}
document.getElementById('category_select').addEventListener("change", function () {
child_();
});
child_();
```

```html
<select id="category_select">
   <option value="">Please select</option>
   <option value="1">Electronics</option>
   <option value="2">Appliances</option>
</select>

<select id="type_select">
   <option value="">Please select</option>
   <option value="1">Phones</option>
   <option value="1">Tablets</option>
   <option value="2">Couch</option>
   <option value="2">Refrigerator</option>
   <option value="2">Vacuum</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The problem with `k.options[i].remove()` is that it removes all the child options one by one as I change options on the parent.

Comment: If you want to show child again on parent change then don't use `remove`

Comment: so which options should I use to make it disappear from the dropdown list without removing it ?

Comment: Please check my answer! If you have any problem, tell me

Comment: Your answer doesn't fix the issue. When `electronics` is selected in `category_select` for example, all the other options are still accessible. My goal is to make them invisible from the drop-down without removing them

Comment: Updated answer! please check

Comment: Options still visible. I would like to make it invisible. Any idea ?

Comment: Where its visible, can you send the screenshot

Comment: Are you update the code, which i submit in my answer because here working fine, and check your browser console, is there any error

Comment: Check my JSfiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/9mogzb0t/5/`. I copy pasted your code in a `sandbox`

Comment: same result. It does disable it but can still see. Can you edit the JSfiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/9mogzb0t/12/`

Comment: I can still see the options although they are disabled ... I'd like to make them disappear

Comment: Here is fiddle screenshot, everything works find http://prntscr.com/ke3nor

Comment: okay that was a browser issue. Safari shows the disabled options. How can I solve this ?

Comment: My framework is RoR and the dropdown options are coming from the database. So this line `var options = {"1": ["Phones", "Tablets"], "2": ["Couch", "Refrigerator", "Vacuum"]};` doesnt make sense.

Comment: works in a sandbox but doesn't in a browser. The first solution worked fine in all browser except safari. here is a console error `https://ibb.co/gfJ3Jz`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to re-display them later, you can remove them by setting their CSS to `display: none`, and display them again with `removeProperty('display')`.

You can also feel free to move `child_` and `parent` outside of the listener, to reduce unnecessary nesting:

```js
function parent_() {
  return document.getElementById('category_select').value;
}

function child_() {
  let k = document.getElementById('type_select');
  for (let i = 0; i < k.options.length; ++i) {
    if (k.options[i].value === parent_()) {
      k.options[i].style.removeProperty('display');
    } else if (k.options[i].value !== parent_()) {
      k.options[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  k.selectedIndex = 0;
}
document.getElementById('category_select').addEventListener("change", child_);
```

```html
<select id="category_select">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Electronics</option>
  <option value="2">Appliances</option>
</select>

<select id="type_select">
  <option value="" disabled="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Phones</option>
  <option value="1">Tablets</option>
  <option value="2">Couch</option>
  <option value="2">Refrigerator</option>
  <option value="2">Vacuum</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? You might include the HTML in your question to ensure that your issue is reproducible

Comment: See edit - the problem was in your HTML. You gave the `option`s `disabled` attributes, which do not get removed when the `display` style changes. Just remove those in the HTML and it works as expected

Comment: @coback Did you check the snippet?

Comment: Did you really press "Run code snippet"? The live demo seems to be just fine to me, can you explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: Yes, works just fine. Select Electronics and only Phones and Tablets are seen on the right. Select Appliances, and the same for Couch/Refrigerator/Vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

using `<optgroup>` will be easier to solve the problem.

removing the child will not append back to the select box;  so we are hiding the selected item from child select box at a time. 
here is the pseudo code

```js
const parent_category = document.getElementById('category_select');
const child_category = document.getElementById('type_select');
const optgroup = child_category.querySelectorAll('optgroup');

let selectedNode;
parent_category.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  let selectedValue = e.target.value;
  child_category.selectedIndex = -1; // deselect previouly selected option
  if (selectedNode) {
    selectedNode.hidden = false;
  }
  Array.from(optgroup).forEach((node) => {
    let nv = node.getAttribute('value');
    if (nv !== selectedValue) {
      selectedNode = node;
      node.hidden = true;
      // if you remove the child than no way to append back to select box
      // while (node.firstChild) {
      //     node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
      // }
      // child_category.removeChild(node);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="category_select">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Electronics</option>
  <option value="2">Appliances</option>
</select>
<select id="type_select">
  <option value="" disabled="">Please select</option>
  <optgroup label="Electronics" value="1">
    <option value="P">Phones</option>
    <option value="T">Tablets</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Appliances" value="2">
    <option value="C">Couch</option>
    <option value="R">Refrigerator</option>
    <option value="V">Vacuum</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```